# Problem in sending message using multiple addresses in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I've created an application that's using multiple Gmail accounts to send email. But instead of displaying actual sender of the email in 'From' header, I want another Gmail address on that header.

I've already set 'From' sender with desirable email address but am getting the actual email sender's address.

Could anyone please tell me how can I stop Gmail overriding my address?

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail, Go Settings -> Accounts -> Add another email address you own. This will go through an approval process to prove you own that address. You will then be able to send from it.

Comment: how should I do if I've more than hundred gmail's account? How can I approve so many addresses to one particular address like that quickly?

Comment: @Avatar: I'm wondering why you need so many Gmail accounts. I'm wondering why you need to send *from* so many Gmail accounts. Trying to get around some anti-spam measures, perhaps? I expect it's a purposeful decision by Google to not allow setting up e-mail address forwarding in bulk. You should probably set up your own SMTP server.